# Loading the multi folder image data set in python 3?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, dataset, load

I have a dataset folder in my *C:* drive and the **dataset** folder has two main folders **training_data** and **test_data**.

***training_data*** has two sub-folders **cats** & **dogs**. The sub-folder has ***8000*** images for training the system.
On the other side ***test_set*** also has the same **cats** & **dogs** sub-folders. It has **2000** images.

I know little about the coding to classic ***Neural Network*** but I am confused in loading the dataset and fitting into the model at the last.

Since I am new in this field so your help will be great for me, thanking you in advance.

**I am using Keras framework.**

Comment: what framework do you use? Keras, TensorFlow, PyTorch?

Comment: I am using Keras

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading your images using an [ImageGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). This one handles to load the data and you can even perform augmentation on those data.